# Is there inflationary solution in $R^2$ theory in Jordan frame?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, curvature, cosmological-inflation, modified-gravity

In the Starobinsky $R^2$ inflation model, one usually uses a conformal transformation from Jordan frame to Einstein frame in which the action can be written just like Einstein action + scalar field action. Then the inflationary solution can be derived in this Einstein frame.
However, is it possible to derive the inflationary solutions in the Jordan frame directly, without the conformal transformation? If the physics in these two frames are the same, there should be the case, right?